# Appending/Adding a string in the middle of an element of a list

Tags: python

Say I have a list:

```
mylist = [element1, element2, element3, ...... ,elementn]
```

And the elements are like:

```
element1 = 'object1 = "value1" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"'
```

and all the other elements are the same, except for a minor difference in `"value3"`

Replace each of the elements in the list with the likes of element1 and you'll get how the list looks like.

I have a string:

```
to_place = 'something_to_append'
```

What I want is to append `to_place` at the end of `object1 = "value1"`, so that it looks like `object1 = "value1something_to_append"`

I've tried looping through each element, trying to find `value1` (which is the same accross the elements of the list), and using string append functions, but I'm just not getting the results I want.

Any help will be appreciated. (I'll upload the code I've tried in a few minutes, having a bit of trouble)

Edit: Adding the code:

```
element = [element1, element2, element3]
s = 'something_to_append'
for u in element:
    if 'object1="value"' in u.split():
        u = u + s
print(element)
```

As for the output, I'm getting the same list as before.
P.S: Using Python 2.7, on PyCharm, on Windows 10

Comment: What have you tried? Could you add 3 things to your question: the code you used, the incorrect output you get and the output you wish to get?

Comment: Yeah, in a moment. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Can you try `for i, u in enumerate(element):`  `if 'object1="value"' in u.split():`       `u[i]= u[i] + s`

Comment: @Bazingaa this won't work obviously.

Comment: @Bazingaa It did not work.

Comment: I realized the mistake. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, strings are immutable in python. So you can never change a string in place - you can only copy it, do something with that copy and create a new string from that. In your case, you could define a function to do that for you:

```
def insert_something(element, value, appendix):
    index_after = element.find(value) + len(value)
    return element[:index_after] + appendix + element[index_after:]
```

afterwards, iterate over your list, doing this with every element, and creating a new list (i'm sure that there are more elegant ways than this, but this is what i came up with rn):

```
new_list = [insert_something(item, '"value1', to_place) for item in mylist]
```

**Edit:**
To stay closer to your own code: what you have to do is use `enumerate`, since you are going to change the list, which will affect the position of your elements. Could look something like this:

```
element = [element1, element2, element3]
s = 'something_to_append'
for idx, u in enumerate(element):
    if 'object1="value"' in u.split():
        u = u[:-1] + s + '"'
        element[idx] = u
```

Both of these work and return what you want, so it's just up to you what you like better :) though the first one is a more general approach for any similar problem.

Comment: Staying closer to my code isn't a priority, writing code that works is. Your approach certainly did work, but with a slight mistake. I ended up with `"value1"something_to_append`, whereas, `"value1something_to_append"` is what I wanted. But it's a solid approach nevertheless.Edit: found the right answer, just replacing `"value1"` with `"value1` worked out perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: this can be fixed by using `'"value1'` as the function argument, which will place `something_to_append` inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to generalise this a bit by splitting the string using `shlex.split` so to preserve any whitespace in the value parts, assigning the values to a dict, updating those values, then reconstructing the string, eg:

```
import shlex
from collections import OrderedDict

def f(text, **kwargs):
    split = shlex.split(text)
    d = OrderedDict(zip(split[::3], split[2::3]))
    d.update((k, d[k] + v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in d)
    return ' '.join('{} = "{}"'.format(k, v) for k, v in d.items())
```

Then use it as:

```
element1 = 'object1 = "value1" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"'
updated_string = f(element1, object1='append here')
# 'object1 = "value1append here" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"'
```

Might want to consider introducing a few more checks for robustness but should work equally as well as other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting with a regex may work for you. Here, I put it in a function to make it easier to use:

```
import re

def append_to(in_value, value_to_search, value_to_append):
    value_to_search = re.escape(value_to_search)
    return re.sub(
        '"({})"'.format(value_to_search),
        '"\\1{}"'.format(value_to_append),
        in_value,
    )

my_list = [append_to(item, 'value3', 'something_to_append') for item in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler answer if all "value1" are the same :

```
mylist = [element1, element2, element3, ...... ,elementn]
to_place = "something_to_append"
newlist = [elem.replace("value1","value1"+to_place) for elem in mylist]
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a function `f`

```
def f(x, y):
    return x[:17] + y + x[17:]
```

Then do

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(mylist)
['object1 = "value1" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"',
 'object1 = "value1" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"',
 'object1 = "value1" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"']
>>> to_place = 'something_to_append'
>>> new_list = [f(x, to_place) for x in mylist]
>>> pprint(new_list)
['object1 = "value1something_to_append" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"',
 'object1 = "value1something_to_append" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"',
 'object1 = "value1something_to_append" object2 = "value2" object3 = "value3"']
```